# question about open balls in a vector space

Tags: vector-spaces

Suppose V is a normed vector space and $x_1,x_2 \in V,  0<r_1,r_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ show that $B_{r_1}(x_1)+B_{r_2}(x_2) = B_{r_1+r_2}(x_1+x_2)$

I did the easy part and showed that $B_{r_1}(x_1)+B_{r_2}(x_2) \subseteq B_{r_1+r_2}(x_1+x_2)$
But I really struggle with the opposite direction and would love any help, thanks in advance

Comment: For some simplification, can you see $B_r(x) = x+ B_r(0)$?  (This is basically the definition of the distance in terms of the norm)

Comment: how would that might help? @BrianMoehring

Comment: helpplease, come on! applying this transformation to your 3 balls, what is the (simpler) equality remaining to prove?

Comment: @helpplease Please try to answer the questions you're asked in these forums.  The purpose is usually to either clarify the question or inform answers.  My question in particular  had two purposes: (1) the stated purpose of simplifying the problem and (2) the possibly more important purpose of quickly gauging what type of answer is appropriate for you.  Either a "no, I can't see that" or a "yes, I can see that" would help, and then asking "how would that help?" would be okay.  Remember I don't know you and don't know if you're just being obstinate by responding to my question with a question.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I am really sorry I missed the "can you" part, this is my first time in math exchange and I am not a native English speaker. Thanks a lot for your help and guidance, I wouldn't want you to waste any more time on my question because it had already been answered, but again Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using
$$B_r(x)=x+rB_1(0)\quad\text{ and }\quad a B_1(0)+b B_1(0)=(a+b)B_1(0)$$
we have
$$
B_{r_1}(x_1)+B_{r_2}(x_2)\\
=x_1+r_1\cdot B_1(0)+x_2+r_2\cdot B_1(0)\\
=(x_1+x_2)+(r_1+r_2)\cdot B_1(0)\\
=B_{r_1+r_2}(x_1+x_2).
$$

Lets prove that indeed $a B_1(0)+b B_1(0)=(a+b)B_1(0)$:

Let $av+bw\in a B_1(0)+b B_1(0)$. Then $av+bw=(a+b)\cdot x$ with $x=\frac{av+bw}{a+b}$ which has norm $\vert\vert x \vert \vert=\frac{\vert\vert av+bw \vert \vert}{a+b}\leq \frac{a\vert\vert v \vert \vert+b\vert\vert w \vert \vert}{a+b}< 1$. This proves $a B_1(0)+b B_1(0)\subset(a+b)B_1(0)$. The other direction should be simpler.

Comment: Depends on your context; what you need it for. But since you asked I would say yes - prove it. Sure you could also directly prove your exercise, however it is more elegant to split you arguments into single observations. Especially here where they might be useful observations for later on, like $B_r(x)=x+rB_1(0)$.

Comment: Is the other direction:
$x \in (a+b)B_1(0)$ so $||x||<a+b$ so $||x||-a<b$, and since $B_1(0)$ is open there exists $\varepsilon > 0 $ so that  $||x||-a+\varepsilon<b$ so $x_1=x*(||x||-(a-\varepsilon)/||x||$ and $x_2=x*(a-\varepsilon)/||x||$

Comment: No its a general fact that $(a+b)X\subset aX+bX$ for a subset $X\subset V$(why?); keep it simple